# Twig extension disable auto escape

Tags: symfony, twig, escaping, symfony4, twig-extension

I made a twig extension to be able to call functions in the templates, but unfortunately now the rendered html content of these functions is escaped. Do you have any idea how I could disable that?

FrontendTwigExtension.php

```
class FrontendTwigExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
/**
 * @var DataProviderService
 */
private $dataProvider;

/**
 * FrontendTwigExtension constructor.
 * @param DataProviderService $dataProvider
 */
public function __construct(DataProviderService $dataProvider)
{
    $this->dataProvider = $dataProvider;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getFunctions(): array
{
    return array(
        new Twig_Function('getProductDetailData',
            [$this, 'getProductDetailData'],
            ['needs_environment' => true]
        ),
        new Twig_Function('getPageHeader',
            [$this, 'getPageHeader'],
            ['needs_environment' => true]
        )
    );
}

/**
 * @param Twig_Environment $env
 * @return string
 * @throws Twig_Error_Loader
 * @throws Twig_Error_Runtime
 * @throws Twig_Error_Syntax
 */
public function getPageHeader(Twig_Environment $env): string
{
    return $env->render('Component/PageHeader/pageHeader.html.twig');
}

/**
 * @param Twig_Environment $env
 * @return string
 * @throws Twig_Error_Loader
 * @throws Twig_Error_Runtime
 * @throws Twig_Error_Syntax
 */
public function getProductDetailData(Twig_Environment $env): string
{
    $service = new ProductDetailDataService($this->dataProvider);
    return $env->render('Module/ProductDetailPage/productDetailData.html.twig',
        [
            'productData' => $service->getData()
        ]
    );
}
}
```

template.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block pageHeader %}
    {{ getPageHeader() }}
    {{ getProductDetailData() }}
{% endblock %}
```

services.yaml

```
App\Extension\FrontendTwigExtension:
    arguments:
        - '@App\DataProvider\DataProviderService'
    tags:
        - { name: 'twig.extension' }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You nedd to set the `is_safe` option:

```
['needs_environment' => true, 'is_safe' => ['html']]
```

Comment: Yeah, I just found it out myself.. ^^ Thanks for the answer though. Will keep it for future references.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `raw` function in twig.

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block pageHeader %}
    {{ getPageHeader()|raw }}
    {{ getProductDetailData()|raw }}
{% endblock %}
```

source: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html

Comment: The question is about a custom filter/function OP introduced. Using `raw` here is not recommend as you can just mark the filter as safe within the extension. See G1.3's answer

Comment: @DarkBee It will have the same effect... Using `safe` is equal to using `raw`. One is used in the controller, the second in twig. No differences at all.

Comment: It will have the same effect, but in terms of usability and ease of use I don't find this answer to be usefull

Comment: @DarkBee `'is_safe' => ['html']` will just call `raw` for twig... I don't see how it's not usefull, and how hard it's to use... Both answers are valid. The OP choose the first, nothing more... The minus point is just saying to reader that my answer isn't valid.... Yet it's... In care of the OP, he use customs functions called in twig, but there will be case when you won't be doing that, and still have to render HTML. Thus using `raw`. This is just one of the two possible solution. Twig filters exists to be used.

Comment: The downvote indicates the answer is not useful for this question. Not that it's invalid. Imagine if someone wrote a filter which he/she had to use 100+ times in the project, then he/she would have to place the filter `raw` behind the custom filter/function a 100+ times... See my point why this is not so useful?